# GeoListPlot: coloring points

Tags: geographics

I have 2 lists (data1,data2) of Lat/Lon-values from a SQL database. With GeoPosition[data1] resp. GeoPosition[data2] I have now two GeoPosition objects. I want to show all data points within a map via GeoListPlot. This works but all points have the same color. How can I change the color for the first list to blue and for the second list to red?

regards
Volker

---

Thank you, Alexey and David, for the help. This works, although a internet connection is needed. @Kuba: sorry, you are right, it was rather short.
For clarification:
Step 1: getting lat/lon-pairs from a database into 2 different lists data1 and data2
Step 2: convert the lists into geoposition objects with
gdata1 = GeoPosition[data1] and gdata2 = GeoPosition[data2]
Step 3: GeoListPlot[{gdata1, gdata2}] yields to an error message "Coordinate {{8.786667, 62.80830897297128}, {7.1427439999999995`, 59.26734059658699}, {6.766774999999999, 59.941481559066624`}, {7.684830999999999, 61.3055909134758}, {12.241633, 60.170487617305945`}} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form." and a second one for gdata2.
Step 4: GeoListPlot[gdata1] resp. GeoListPlot[gdata2] produced two maps with the plotted points.
Problem: bring them together into just one map, the points from gdata1 in one color, those from gdata2 in another color.

Thank you for help
Volker

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. p.s. isn't `GeoListPlot[{list1, list2}]` enough?

Answer (score 1):

You need `PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}` or other specification.

```
GeoListPlot[{{Entity["Country", "Canada"], 
   Entity["Country", "Mexico"]}, {Entity["Country", "Egypt"]}}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Dashed, EdgeForm[{Green, Thick}], Opacity[1]], 
   Directive[Red, Opacity[.2], EdgeForm[{Thick, Black, Dashed}]]}]
```

Comment: I converted your boxes into `InputForm` by applying `InputForm` to the first argument of the `GeoListPlot`.